# Import Third Party Framework in custom ios framework

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm creating a custom framework, but i'm having problems when i try to import third party framework. In a objective-c header file i import the framework, but when i compile i receive the following error: "Include of non-modular header inside framework module".

Answer (score 0):

You can set **Allow Non-modular includes in Framework Modules** in Build Settings for the affected target to YES.

[image]

Comment: i've set "Allow Non-modular includes in Framework Modules" to yes in the target, but nothing changed

Comment: i've done this for all of other header files, but the problem i have now is with a third party compiled framework, maybe i've to expose the headers of this framework, but i don't know how.